# read memory outside a program without segment faults

Tags: c++, memory

Is it possible to read memory addresses (real, not virtual) without throwing a segment fault? I wish to read all live, used memory addresses and log findings.

Comment: Not directly, but the operating system might provide a function you can use to do it. (I know both Windows and Linux have ways to access other processes' virtual memory, but no idea about physical memory)

Comment: On Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040303/accessing-physical-address-from-user-space, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894160/accessing-physical-memory-from-linux-kernel, http://falsinsoft.blogspot.ru/2013/10/access-physical-memory-in-linux.html

Comment: Linux side seems easy, but Windows is a bit tricky (I'm a bit HAL rusty). Thank you all for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the OS you are using.

It should be possible, but you will need to write a kernel driver to interface between the OS and the hardware, and this code will have to run as a driver (assuming Windows, since users cannot directly interface with physical memory).